# SQL Cast works in Select but not in Where clause

Tags: sql-server, where-clause

I have an oddity I'm struggling to understand in a SQL Server statement.  Hopefully someone can help.

In a query to return Incidents returned the query works fine so I know all the links are OK and I have this in the Select clause to return the day:

```
Select Cast(DATENAME(WEEKDAY, Cast(dbo.TimeZone(Incidents.IncidentDate, Sites.TimeZone) As Date)) As VarChar) As 'IncidentDay',
```

which correctly returns the day of the week as a varchar.

I also want to allow the day to be part of the Where criteria so I pass a varchar variable @IncidentDay to the query and added this to the Where clause:

```
Where (@IncidentDay Is Null 
    Or Cast(DATENAME(WEEKDAY, Cast(dbo.TimeZone(Incidents.IncidentDate, Sites.TimeZone) As Date)) As VarChar) = @IncidentDay)
```

However, if I pass a value to @IncidentDay no results are returned.  The Cast statement is identical and I've used Cast elsewhere in the Where statement to filter by date without problem.

Can anyone shed any ideas on why the day filter is not working?

Thanks.

Edit:  the responses so far to use Case do not work for me and suggest I need to clarify the question.

The issue is that I need to have in my Where clause a condition to compare the day of the week (for example 'Friday') of a stored date against a variable passed to the query.

The Select Cast.. statement correctly returns the day of the week as a varchar, but the same Cast.. statement in the Where clause does not evaluate against the passed varchar variable.  I need to check for Null as the query is also called against other criteria where the @IncidentDay variable would not be set.

Comment: And your variable is varchar or date type? I think the problem is there(remove the varchar cast and keep the date)

Comment: @sagi, the variable is the day of the week, for example 'Friday', so it needs to be a varchar not a date.

Comment: Firstly what datatpe is `@IncidentDay`? - post _all_ of your SQL not just bits of it. Second, what does this look like: `Select Cast(DATENAME(WEEKDAY, Cast(dbo.TimeZone(Incidents.IncidentDate, Sites.TimeZone) As Date)) As VarChar) As IncidentDay, @IncidentDay as C2, CASE WHEN Cast(DATENAME(WEEKDAY, Cast(dbo.TimeZone(Incidents.IncidentDate, Sites.TimeZone) As Date)) As VarChar) = @IncidentDay THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END As Compare From MyTable`

Comment: What collation is the database (not case sensitive is it?) Also be careful of using `cast` with dates. I always recommend using `CONVERT` with an explicit format code. It's also a bit concerning that a function called `TimeZone` appears to return a `varchar` not a `date`

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid you pointed me to the solution in your first comment.  The IncidentDay variable was declared as varchar.  Changing this to varchar(max) resolves the issue and my Where clause works fine. Thanks.

Comment: Also, @Nick.McDermaid, the TimeZone function does return a date.  The varchar is the result of the datename conversion.

Comment: `varchar` = `varchar(1)`. Therefore whatever you were putting into your variable was being truncated to one character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although it was only mentioned in the comments, your variable was defined like this:

```
@IncidentDay VARCHAR
```

This is equivalent to

```
@IncidentDay VARCHAR(1)
```

Which means anything going into the variable is truncated to one character. So 'Thursday' gets turned into 'T' which obviously is not equivalent to 'Thursday'

Also this smaller expression should be equivalent to the expression you are currently using:

```
DATENAME(
    WEEKDAY,
    dbo.TimeZone(Incidents.IncidentDate, Sites.TimeZone)
)
```

You are doing a lot of redundant casting.

Answer (score 0):

In your query OR clause used.

If your intention is whenever @IncidentDay is null then all records should come and if @IncidentDay having any value then it should filter in that date value. Then the below code will work.

Note: Here you need to send "A" instead of  NULL for @IncidentDay if there is no search

```
AND CASE 
        WHEN @IncidentDay 'A'
            THEN 'A'
        ELSE Cast(DATENAME(WEEKDAY, Cast(dbo.TimeZone(Incidents.IncidentDate, Sites.TimeZone) AS DATE)) AS VARCHAR)
        END = @IncidentDay
```

Answer (score 0):

just use this

```
AND  Cast(DATENAME(WEEKDAY, Cast(dbo.TimeZone(Incidents.IncidentDate, Sites.TimeZone) AS DATE)) AS VARCHAR) = CASE 
    WHEN @IncidentDay IS NULL THEN Cast(DATENAME(WEEKDAY, Cast(dbo.TimeZone(Incidents.IncidentDate, Sites.TimeZone) AS DATE)) AS VARCHAR)
    ELSE  @IncidentDay END
```

Answer (score 0):

Ensuring the variable is defined as varchar(max) not just varchar has resolved this issue.

Thank you for your comments.