# Date CAST in WHERE clause does not return items

Tags: sql, sql-server, casting, sql-server-2012, where-clause

I have a problem with SQL query that has a CAST function in it, so this is my condition:

```
CASE
  WHEN FYStartMonths = 1 
  THEN 
    'Period ' + CAST((MONTH(EndDate) + 1) / 2 AS VARCHAR) + ' ' + CAST(YEAR(EndDate) AS VARCHAR)
  ELSE
    'Period ' + CAST((MONTH(EndDate) + 1) / 2 AS VARCHAR) + ' ' + CAST(YEAR(EndDate) AS VARCHAR) + ' - ' + CAST(YEAR(DATEADD(YEAR, 1, EndDate)) AS VARCHAR)
END AS FormattedFilingPeriod
```

So the results of this is something like this

`Period 3 2022 - 2023`

And the SELECT clause looks like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM ActiveItems
WHERE FormattedFilingPeriod LIKE '%' + 'Period 3 2022 - 2023' + '%'
```

The problem is when I'm adding a WHERE clause under the SELECT it just does not return the items if I specify `Period 3 2022 - 2023`, it returns items only when I'm specifying something partialy like `Period` or `2022 - 2023`, but f.e. `3 2022 - 2023` will not return anything. I have no idea why this happening so I would be glad to hear your thoughts.

I've tried to overwrite case conditions with the format, changed casting to AS VARCHAR(MAX) like was mentioned in this question [SQL Cast works in Select but not in Where clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35290897/sql-cast-works-in-select-but-not-in-where-clause) but this doesn't work for me.

Comment: Considering that `FormattedFilingPeriod` is defined in the `SELECT` you should be getting an error; you can't reference columns defined in the `SELECT` by their alias.

Comment: https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length

Comment: FormattedFilingPeriod is defined inside of the CTE called ActiveItems, forgot to mention

Comment: Maybe you should show ALL the code then, not just portions here and there. Table definition, sample data and desired output would go a long way to making this answerable.

Comment: You will be SIGNIFICANTLY better performance by doing the WHERE clause check on the actual date value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic for the `WHERE` clause in the question should be equivalent to this:

```
WHERE FYStartMonths = 1
    AND EndDate >= DateFromParts(2022, 5, 1) AND EndDate < DateFromParts(2022, 6, 1)
```

Writing the `WHERE` clause like this instead will perform **massively better**, because you can still use indexes on the `EndDate` column and you're no longer doing conversion operations on *every row in the table.*

Additionally, this should make the fix for the issue in the question more obvious. The question isn't entirely clear, but it seems like the problem is the value in the `FormattedFilingPeriod` column won't match when `FYStartMonths = 1`, because the `Period` text is missing. Writing the `WHERE` clause this way makes it easy to just remove that condition.

But it also looks a little like this is based on a search filter, where a user might enter anything or select certain pre-formatted queries. In that case, you're still MUCH better off writing front-end code to parse those queries so they can be translated in SQL `WHERE` clause expressions as above.